# Java - for loop related query

Tags: java

I want to get the index of first 'd' letter in my String array input.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int i,j,p1=0,p2=0;
    String grid[] = new String[5];
    for(i=0; i<5; i++)
        grid[i] = sc.next();

    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<5;j++)
        {
            if(grid[i].charAt(j)=='d')
            {
                p1=i;
                p2=j;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(p1+"\n"+p2);
}
}
```

### input
---d-

---d-
-d---
--d--
output
4
2

It is always giving me the last 'd' index, though I'm running loop from (0,0) to (5,5)
Whereas, if I made changes in for loop and ran it from (i=4; i>=0; i--) then the problem is solved. Why?

Comment: You are looking for the index of d? Why not use String method indexOf()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because when you use `break` it takes you of the inner `for` loop only and the outer loop keeps running for the next strings in `grid` array. Also, you should run inner loop for `0` to `grid[i].length()-1`.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT. 
    Your class should be named Solution. */
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int r = sc.nextInt();
    int c = sc.nextInt();
    int i,j,p1=0,p2=0;
    String grid[] = new String[5];
    for(i=0; i<5; i++)
        grid[i] = sc.next();

    boolean found = false;
    for(i=0;i<5;i++) {
        for(j=0;j<grid[i].length();j++) {
            if(grid[i].charAt(j)=='d') {
                p1=i;
                p2=j;
                found = true;
                break;
            }
            if(found) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(p1+"\n"+p2);
}
}
```

Comment: Thank You. I thought 'break' statement would take me out of both loops.

Comment: else write break outer loop

Comment: @NoorAhmedNatali yes can use that too, thank you.

Comment: pls press up arrow on my answer if it help you

Answer (score 0):

```
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    int i,j,p1=0,p2=0;
    String grid=  "How do you do"; // you can take input as " scannerobj.nextLine()"
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<5;j++)
        {
            if(grid.charAt(j) == 'd')
            {
                p1=i;
                p2=j;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(p1+"\n"+p2);
}
}
```

or you can use :

```
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String[] args) {
    /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT. Your class should be named Solution. */
    
    int i,j,p1=0,p2=0;
    String grid=  "How do you do"; // you can take input as "scannerobj.nextLine()
    for(i=0;i<grid.length();i++)
    {
            if(grid.charAt(i) == 'd')
            {
                p1=i;
                break;
            }

    }
    System.out.println(p1+"\n");
}
}
```

Comment: and why do you need 2 loops we can do it in 1 loop

Comment: I was using a string array because the input was of multiple lines. [link](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/botclean?hr_b=1) this is the question

Comment: do you want d each and every string ..?

Answer (score 0):

Copy this Whole code

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyClass {
    
    
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      ArrayList<String> in = new ArrayList<String>();
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        int p1=0,p2=0;
        while (s.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = s.nextLine();
            in.add(line);
            if (line != null && line.equalsIgnoreCase("END")) {
                System.out.println("Output list : " + in);
                break;
            }

        }
        outerloop:
        for(int i=0;i< in.size();i++)
        {
            // System.out.print(i+" "+ in.get(i));
            for(int j=0;j < in.get(i).length();j++)
            {
                if (in.get(i).charAt(j) == 'd')
                {
                    p1=i;
                    p2=j;
                    break outerloop;
                    
                }
                
            }
        }
        
        System.out.print(p1 +" "+ p2);
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Be specific while asking your question. As per your question you want to get the first index of the letter 'd' in a string input then this will be the code.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int i,index=0;
        String grid= sc.nextLine(); //takes any string 
        for(i=0;i<grid.length();i++)
        {
           
                if(grid.charAt(i) == 'd')
                {
                    index=i;
                    break;
                }
        }
        System.out.println(index);
    }

}
```

```
Input
---d-
Output
3
```

if you want to take multiple queries/inputs then this will be the code

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int queries=sc.nextInt(); //number of queries
        while(queries-->0)
        {
            int i,index=0;
            String grid= sc.next(); //takes any string 
            for(i=0;i<grid.length();i++)
            {
               
                    if(grid.charAt(i) == 'd')
                    {
                        index=i;
                        break;
                    }
            }
            System.out.print(index+" ");
        }
        
    }

}
```

```
input
2
---d-
-----

output 
3 
0
```